# Set number of partitions in CassandraTable

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra-2.0

I'm using spark with cassandra, and i'm selecting data from cassandra using this request :

```
val i = sc.cassandraTable[(ClientID, Interaction)](Keyspace, Table).
  select("a", "b", "c", "d").where("a in ?", timesIntervalWindows)
```

And this request return more than 5000000 rows but the problem is that my RDD contain only one partition !!!!
So i tried to change this property of Spark Context :

```
conf.set("spark.cassandra.input.split.size", "10000")
```

but it still creating only one partition. 
Ps: i don't wanna use Coaless or repartition because it schuffle all the data in the network and takes a lot of time. 
Can some one tell me what i'm doing wrong or how to fix this problem !

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting the partitioner on the RDD? It looks like there is a `CassandraRDDPartitioner`

Answer (score 2):

Input split size just uses an estimate of the number of Cassandra Partitions (not rows) that will be in a given Spark Partition. Scale the number to try to correspond to the number or C* partitions you want in side of a Spark Partition.

Current work is also being done on letting you set a guaranteed number of partitions.